# Export QGIS Print Composer to CAD

Tags: qgis, export, cad

Is there a way to import a .qpt file to a CAD software?

Explaining:

I just finished a print composer for my project in QuantumGIS but I have a collegue that only works with AutoCAD, and he is the one who is going to do the follow up of this project.

So, I have to export my work so that he can use the same layout for the same client!

Can it be done? Or the only solution is to export as image and then do it "by hand"?
But what about the fonts/size of titles/legend, etc, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export your work to pdf. Try to convert pdf file to dwg. http://cadsofttools.com/pdf-to-dwg-online/

Comment: I tried that tool. Unfortunately when I open the dwg file, everything is not formatted... Texts and lettering can't be rewritten.. Guess there is no way better way to solve this problem, that fixing it by hand! If anyone knows a more efficient way to fixed this problem, please let me know! Unfortunately what you get in speed and functionality of QGIS print composer, you are apparently losing it on weak export capability... Thank you, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You could try exporting the print composer to SVG instead of PDF.  You might be able to [import SVGs directly into CAD](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/design-validate-document/importing-svg-files-as-sketches/td-p/4534941) (I can't comment as I don't use CAD) or you can also import them into inkscape and export them to dxf or dwg using 'save-as'.